# Understanding option records in Wordpress Database

Tags: php, wordpress, serialization

I try to understand some option records from Wordpress database. For example, the following record belongs to the option named as `c2c_configure_smtp`

```
a:12:{s:9:"use_gmail";s:0:"";s:4:"host";s:19:"smtp.webfaction.com";s:4:"port";s:3:"465";s:11:"smtp_secure";s:3:"ssl";s:9:"smtp_auth";s:1:"1";s:8:"wordwrap";s:0:"";s:5:"debug";s:0:"";s:10:"from_email";s:9:"from_name";s:6:"Destek";s:8:"_version";s:3:"3.1";}
```

I guess this is serialization of some php array, right? Is it possible for a human to understand this data format? What does `a:12` or `s:0` mean?

Comment: a:12 -- an array with 12 entries / 
s:9  -- a string with a length of 9 / 
s:0 -- a string with a length of 0
(so it's datatype:length)

Answer (score 0):

use php built in serialize () and unserialize () functions. according to data you given, you should expect array